# One-Step Smooth Manifold Structure.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I found the following lemma in Lee's book on smooth manifolds.

> **Lemma 1.14** (One-Step Smooth Manifold Structure).   Let M be a set, and
>   suppose we are given a collection {Uα} of subsets of M, together with
>   an injective map ϕα : Uα → Rn for each α, such that the following
>   properties are satisfied.
>   (i) For each α, Ueα = ϕα(Uα) is an open
>   subset of Rn.
>   (ii) For each α and β, ϕα(Uα ∩ Uβ) and ϕβ(Uα ∩ Uβ) are
>   open in Rn.
>   (iii) Whenever Uα ∩ Uβ 6= ∅, ϕβ ◦ ϕ−1 α : ϕα(Uα ∩ Uβ) →
>   ϕβ(Uα ∩ Uβ) is smooth.
>   (iv) Countably many of the sets Uα cover M.
>   (v) Whenever p, q are distinct points in M, either there exists some
>   Uα containing both p and q or there exist disjoint sets Uα, Uβ with p
>   ∈ Uα and q ∈ Uβ.
>
> Then M has a unique smooth manifold structure such that each (Uα, ϕα)
>   is a smooth chart.

Is condition (v) different than saying that the collection $\{U_{\alpha} \}$ is a covering of $M$?

Comment: When you say $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is a covering of $M$, your $\alpha$ might belong to an uncountable set. Condition $(iv)$ is stronger than that, as it says, $\alpha$ comes from a countable set.

Comment: @AjayKumarNair my bad, I wanted to say "condition (v)" not "condition (iv)", I eddited.

Comment: It is different. There could be $U_{\alpha}, U_{\beta}$, $p\in U_{\alpha},q\in U_{\beta}$, $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}\neq\phi$.

Comment: @TeebroProkash thanks, I get it now!

Answer (score 2):

Condition 5 is there to make sure that the set is given an Hausdorff topology (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space)